# Link style not showing on Safari

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink, safari

I have a "button" that is basically a link. It's properly styled the way I wanted and shows up like this in Chrome: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOYUl.png)

But in Safari it shows only the text and nothing else.

The code that I have used:

```css
.button-see-more {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 0px 18px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 0.13) 0s;
}

.button-see-more:hover {
  transition: 0.2s;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
 <a href="/project-inadequat.html" class="button-see-more"><p>See More</p></a>
```

I'm pretty sure that I am messing something up and would appreciate knowing what.

Answer (score 0):

I've went ahead and used your code provided to make [this test/preview site](https://deeppinksparsetexts.clit.repl.co/)

It seems like it's working with no issue, so as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70314682/14544118) states; it could just be a cache issue. Clear your browser cache and reopen Safari, and view the site again.

(Currently I am using Safari and the styled link shows fine)